# database questions in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, jdbc

The following query is in SQL:

```
SELECT r.reservation_no, f.flight_no, r.departure_date,
       f.departure_time, f.duration
  FROM flights f, reservations r
 WHERE f.flight_no=r.flight_no AND r.customer_ssn="234567";
```

Print the results to the screen in table form.

I need to make it in such a way that it can be compatible with JDBC.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT r.reservation_no, f.flight_no, r.departure_date, f.departure_time, f.duration FROM flights f, reservations r WHERE f.flight_no=r.flight_no AND r.customer_ssn="234567");
while ( rs.next() ) {
    **String capacity = rs.getString("??????"); -- what should I use here? as I have to take many values from the tables?**
    System.out.println(capacity);
}
```

Comment: mr.Haim...could you please help me in this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String query = "SELECT r.reservation_no, f.flight_no, r.departure_date, f.departure_time, f.duration FROM flights f, reservations r WHERE f.flight_no=r.flight_no AND r.customer_ssn="?" ";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, customer_ssn);
result = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I dont undersatnd 1 thing, we use preparedStatement then we put ? in place of customer _ssn.....then how would you satisfy the condition?

Comment: You set the value of the 1. `?` with the line `ps.setString(1, customer_ssn)`

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly, then in the place of ??? you can have either the column name or the column index number.

Comment: Do you have a known number of entries ? e.g. do you need to check 3 values as in `r.customer_ssn="234567" or r.customer_ssn="12345" or r.customer_ssn="98765"` , or do you have a variable number of entries to check for ?