# sql query via jdbc

Tags: sql, mysql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql query with jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122209/sql-query-with-jdbc)

How dow e find the wuery frok mysql.

Comment: dude. it seems that you are programming right now and at every little problem that comes up you are spontaneously posting it to stackoverflow.

Comment: @leebutts: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: no, actually,,...i have my exam...so am preparing for it by practice these queries....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setDate instead of setString :

```
ps.setDate(2, departure_date );
```

also if you use prepared use question mark in your query like

```
String query =  "INSERT INTO reservations (flight_no, departure_date) VALUES ("?", "?")";
```

Comment: but then where i would put my flight no and departure date if I put ?

Comment: see the example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementSetDate.htm

Comment: String query =  "INSERT INTO reservations (flight_no, departure_date) VALUES (?, ?)";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, "12345");
ps.setDate(2, "2010-05-10" );
result = ps.executeQuery();

Comment: sir,If I have to tell if the operation is successful or not?how do i do it? Like the query has performed the specific task or not?

Comment: see in the example i link it ,  // execute query, and return number of rows created  int rowCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementSetDate.htm

Comment: I cant use the date as it is...I have to change it , ps.setDate(2, departure_date ); - this is wrong...can you plz tell me any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this:

```
String query =  "INSERT INTO reservations (flight_no, departure_date) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

The "?" indicate that you need to provide data for it be inserted into database.

Answer (score 1):

```
String query =  "INSERT INTO reservations (flight_no, departure_date) VALUES (?, ?)";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, flight_no);
ps.setDate(2, departure_date );
result = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the query you must replace parameters with question marks. Use `?` instead of "CSC585" and "2010-05-31". Those question marks will be replaced by values set by `.setString()` and similar methods.